# For looping different files into the same row list

Tags: python-3.x

The problem is that files from the "for" loop are being displayed into different rows. I don't know how many files are going to be included so I wanted to expand the list proportional to the files.

I tried adding ("'" + files + "',") to a single variable and appending the variable to the list

```
import os 

opc = ""
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\testpy")

for f in os.listdir():
    filename, file_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    if file_ext == "":
        continue
    filec, fileI = filename.split(".")
    listd = list(())
    opc += "'" + filec + "',"
    listd.append(opc)
print (listd)
```

When I ran the code, I got this:

```
["'JumpingAroundDogs','Never-Tell-flying','PicturesInHouse_SS90','River-Tall-Running','Run-Run-Run-Down','winnern',"]
```

but What I actually wanted was this:

```
['JumpingAroundDogs','Never-Tell-flying','PicturesInHouse_SS90','River-Tall-Running','Run-Run-Run-Down','winnern']
```

Does anyone have any idea of how to do that?

Comment: dont split at `.` to get the name from the extension. You could have files named ".this.is.not.going.to.work.txt"

Answer (score 0):

Declare your list before the loop, add the names directly to the list. You seem to split the name at `'.'` - this might bork out because you only decompose into 2 elements. Filenames like

```
some.filename.with.extension.txt
```

will decompose into more then 2 elements and throw errors.

```
import os 

opc = ""
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\testpy")

listd = []
for f in os.listdir():
    filename, file_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    if file_ext == "":
        continue
    filec, _ = filename.split(".",2)  # only care about the 1st split
    listd.append(filec)
print (listd)
```